How C++ template functions / classes are linked across libraries
Suppose I have two libraries that instantiated the same template function with the same parameter type. For example
// framework.h that defines a function template
template<typename T> T GetNumFunc() {
    return 1;
}

// lib1.h
int GetNumLib1();

// lib1.cpp
#include "framework.h"
#include "lib1.h"
int GetNumLib1() {
    return GetNumFunc<int>();
}

// lib2.h
int GetNumLib2();

// lib2.cpp
#include "framework.h"
#include "lib2.h"
int GetNumLib2() {
    return GetNumFunc<int>();
}

After compilation, the compiled instantiated template function (GetNumFunc<int>()) should exist in both libraries. When linking these two libraries with my executable, how does the instantiated template function get resolved? Why is there not a multiple-definition issue?
Suppose the compiling options for library 1 and library 2 are different, the instructions generated for GetNumFunc<int>() might differ, resulting in different performance when running. When linking, which translated (compiled) function would be picked? Would this result in performance degradation if the linker picked the one which runs slower? Is it possible to explicitly specify which compiled instructions to use in each .cpp (translation unit)?
My project relies on a bunch of external packages (static libraries). I found the performance of executables in my project degraded after upgrading the packages version. And later I found out the only difference between package upgrade is that the new package version is built with different compiler options, resulting in slower execution. The performance degradation in my executables occurred at std::vector and memory allocation etc, which does not directly rely on the external packages. So I'm suspecting there might be some linking issue.
